# How do I split the plus minus number string in java?

Tags: java, string, split, stringbuilder

**Input :**

String arrr[] = new String[4];

arrr[0] = +2501 +2502 +2503 +2504

arrr[1] = -2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509

arrr[2] = +2501 +2511 -2502 -2505

arrr[3] = +2513 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509

**Output :**

I want separte the string as :

*Positive :*

arrr1[0] = +2501 +2502 +2503 +2504

arrr1[1] = +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509

arrr1[2] = +2501 +2511

arrr1[3] = +2513

*Negative :*

arrr2[0] = -2501 -2504

arrr2[1] = -2502 -2505

arrr2[2] = -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509

```
int nostrt = -1, m = 0;
StringBuilder str4 = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0;i < strbullist.length(); i++)
{    
    char c = strbullist.charAt(i);

    if(nostrt == -1)
    {
        m = i;
        nostrt = 1; 
    }
    if(c=='-')
    {
        
        str4.append(strbullist.substring(m, i));
        nostrt = -1;
        System.out.println(str4);
    }    
}
```

Comment: you already realize "split", now think "by what". I assume the string is like this `"-2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509"`, so it's `"-2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509".split(. . . )` ?

Comment: What you want is two regular expressions, one to match negative numbers, the other to match positive numbers. ``s.replaceAll("\\+\\d*", "")`` This expression matches all sets of only digits with a "+" in front. Replace the "+" with a "-" to match negative numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string on one or more whitespace characters (i.e. `\s+`) and iterate the resulting array to find if an element starts with a positive symbol or a negative symbol.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "+2501 +2502 +2503 +2504 -2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509 +2501 +2511 -2502 -2505 +2513 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509";
        List<String> positiveNums = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> negativeNums = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");

        for (String s : arr) {
            if (s.startsWith("+")) {
                positiveNums.add(s);
            } else if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                negativeNums.add(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Positive numbers: " + positiveNums);
        System.out.println("Negative numbers: " + negativeNums);

        // If you want to store the output into string variables
        String positiveValues = positiveNums.toString();
        String negativeValues = negativeNums.toString();
        System.out.println("Positive numbers: " + positiveValues);
        System.out.println("Negative numbers: " + negativeValues);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Positive numbers: [+2501, +2502, +2503, +2504, +2505, +2506, +2507, +2509, +2501, +2511, +2513]
Negative numbers: [-2501, -2504, -2502, -2505, -2507, -2503, -2511, -2509]
Positive numbers: [+2501, +2502, +2503, +2504, +2505, +2506, +2507, +2509, +2501, +2511, +2513]
Negative numbers: [-2501, -2504, -2502, -2505, -2507, -2503, -2511, -2509]
```

Alternatively, you can also use [regex](https://regex101.com/r/7WZXRJ/1), `\+\d+|\-\d+` which means [one or more](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) digits followed by a plus symbol (i.e. `\+\d+`) or (i.e. `|`)  one or more digits followed by a negative symbol (i.e. `\-\d+`).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "+2501 +2502 +2503 +2504 -2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509 +2501 +2511 -2502 -2505 +2513 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\+\\d+|\\-\\d+").matcher(str);
        List<String> positiveNums = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> negativeNums = new ArrayList<>();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String s = matcher.group();
            if (s.startsWith("+")) {
                positiveNums.add(s);
            } else if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                negativeNums.add(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Positive numbers: " + positiveNums);
        System.out.println("Negative numbers: " + negativeNums);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Positive numbers: [+2501, +2502, +2503, +2504, +2505, +2506, +2507, +2509, +2501, +2511, +2513]
Negative numbers: [-2501, -2504, -2502, -2505, -2507, -2503, -2511, -2509]
```

**In case you want to use `StringBuilder` instead of the `List`:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "+2501 +2502 +2503 +2504 -2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509 +2501 +2511 -2502 -2505 +2513 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509";
        StringBuilder positiveNums = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder negativeNums = new StringBuilder();
        String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");

        for (String s : arr) {
            if (s.startsWith("+")) {
                positiveNums.append(s + " ");
            } else if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                negativeNums.append(s + " ");
            }
        }

        String positiveValues = positiveNums.toString().trim();
        String negativeValues = negativeNums.toString().trim();
        System.out.println("Positive numbers: " + positiveValues);
        System.out.println("Negative numbers: " + negativeValues);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Positive numbers: +2501 +2502 +2503 +2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509 +2501 +2511 +2513
Negative numbers: -2501 -2504 -2502 -2505 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509
```

**Using [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-):**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "+2501 +2502 +2503 +2504 -2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509 +2501 +2511 -2502 -2505 +2513 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509";
        List<String> positiveNums = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> negativeNums = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");

        for (String s : arr) {
            if (s.matches("\\+\\d+")) {
                positiveNums.add(s);
            } else if (s.matches("\\-\\d+")) {
                negativeNums.add(s);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Positive numbers: " + positiveNums);
        System.out.println("Negative numbers: " + negativeNums);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Positive numbers: [+2501, +2502, +2503, +2504, +2505, +2506, +2507, +2509, +2501, +2511, +2513]
Negative numbers: [-2501, -2504, -2502, -2505, -2507, -2503, -2511, -2509]
```

### Update (based on the updated question):

If the strings in your question are elements of a `String[]`, you need an additional loop to iterate this `String[]`. Rest of the things will remain the same.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String[] strArr = { "+2501 +2502 +2503 +2504", "-2501 -2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509", "+2501 +2511 -2502 -2505",
                "+2513 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509" };
        StringBuilder positiveNums = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder negativeNums = new StringBuilder();

        for (String str : strArr) {
            String[] arr = str.split("\\s+");
            for (String s : arr) {
                if (s.startsWith("+")) {
                    positiveNums.append(s + " ");
                } else if (s.startsWith("-")) {
                    negativeNums.append(s + " ");
                }
            }
        }

        String positiveValues = positiveNums.toString().trim();
        String negativeValues = negativeNums.toString().trim();
        System.out.println("Positive numbers: " + positiveValues);
        System.out.println("Negative numbers: " + negativeValues);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Positive numbers: +2501 +2502 +2503 +2504 +2505 +2506 +2507 +2509 +2501 +2511 +2513
Negative numbers: -2501 -2504 -2502 -2505 -2507 -2503 -2511 -2509
```

Comment: Thanks sir, It woeked

Comment: You are most welcome.

Comment: if there are string array and want to match the pattern then how it will work?

Comment: I tried but its taking only last matcher of the string

Comment: @shs - No worries...I've posted the solution (last one in my answer) for this requirement as well.

Comment: Do you have link?

Comment: @shs - Link for what?

Comment: String array pattern match

Comment: @shs - There is no single API to match elements of an array...there are ways e.g. I have posted one (the last one in my answer)...there are many other ways e.g. by using `Stream` API but you have to iterate the array in every case. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Comment: I have edited the que could you please give me a suggestion on that.

Comment: @shs - I've posted an update (the last solution in my answer) to meet this requirement. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic and change according to your need.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class p19 {

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter the size of the array:");
     int size;
     size=sc.nextInt();
     int arr[ ]=new int[size];
  int i,j=0;
  System.out.println("Enter the Element of the array:");
      while(j<size)
     {
         arr[j]=sc.nextInt();
         j++;
     }
      System.out.println("Positive numbers are:");
      for(i=0;i<size;i++)
      {
          if(arr[i]>0)
          {
           System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
          }
      }

      System.out.println("\nNegative numbers are:");
      for(i=0;i<size;i++){
          if(arr[i]<0)
          {
           System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
          }
      }
     sc.close();
     }}
```

Comment: i want just separate it. Its a string not integer.

Comment: str = "2234 -8765 +665";
int[] splited = Integer.parseInt(str.split("\\s+"));

Answer (score 0):

If you want the numbers stored in a string, try this

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter size : ");
        int size = sc.nextInt();
        
        String [] numbers = new String[size];
        String positive = "", negative = "";
        
        System.out.print("Enter number with signs (-) or (+) : ");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            numbers[i] = sc.next();
        }
        
        for(int i =0; i < size; i++){
            if(numbers[i].contains("-")){
                negative += numbers[i] + " ";
            }else if(numbers[i].contains("+")){
                positive += numbers[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println("Negatives : " + negative);
        System.out.println("Positives : " + positive);
```